# How can I de-aliasing `dir` using shell command?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm learning some shell commands on ubuntu 12.04. But I had a hard time unaliasing something I have set before. For example,

```
$ alias dir ls
$ dir
[some files and directories]
$ unalias dir
- no such command.
```

Does Ubuntu not support `dir` command? How can I de-aliasing `dir` using shell command?

Comment: `dir` may not be an alias - for example, on my current system, `which dir` reports `/usr/bin/dir`. In that case you can't unalias it... You could *replace* it with `alias dir=true` or something, though...

Answer (score 1):

First you ahve to define your alias using this syntax:

```
alias dir=ls
```

Then you can check if it worked out:

```
me@foo:~alias
alias dir='ls'
alias l.='ls -d .* --color=auto'
...
```

After this works you can simply unalias with:

```
unalias dir
```

I think the dir command is a binary in Ubuntu, you can check this using:

```
which dir
```

If it gives you a path to an executable you know that dir is no alias.